# Hiding Rows on Another Sheet in a Protected Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a sort of Table of Contents on Sheet2 with ActiveX checkboxes.

If a user selects one of these checkboxes, it will hide that section on another sheet.

I need this to be a protected workbook.

When I click a checkbox, I receive this error:

> "The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet. To make changes, click Unprotect Sheet in the Review tab."

Code to protect the workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wSheetName As Worksheet
For Each wSheetName In Worksheets
    wSheetName.Protect Password:="pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
Next wSheetName
End Sub
```

The code for the checkbox:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Sheet1.Rows("4:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else:
    Sheet1.Rows("4:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Unprotect the sheet do the hiding, reprotect the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `ThisWorkbook` qualifier to the Sub.
Change:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim wSheetName As Worksheet
For Each wSheetName In Worksheets
    wSheetName.Protect Password:="pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

Next wSheetName
End Sub
```

To:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wSheetName As Worksheet
    For Each wSheetName In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wSheetName.Protect Password:="pass", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True

    Next wSheetName
    End Sub
```

Comment: Still receiving the error unfortunately. Now I'm seeing "object doesn't support this property or method" error message too...

Comment: I added in the `AllowFormattingColumns` and `AllowFormattingRows` to the answer.  Take out the `ThisWorkbook` and see if that works.